# Build a histogram in python by giving bins parameters

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have the x and y obtained from a histogram, and I want to rebuild that histogram. How can I do that? I tried this:

```
plt.hist(x,bins=len(x),weights=y)
```

But it seems like the points are not exactly on the center of the bin and they get significantly shifted after a while (the points on the x-axis are not equally spaced).

Comment: Without explaining the exact way `x` and `y` are obtained and what they contain, it is hard to guess your question.  If `x` are x-positions (not bin boundaries) and `y` is the height of the histogram for each `x`, then `plt.bar(x, y)` would show a bar plot similar to a histogram.

Comment: @JohanC Thanks for this! That is what I need. It's just that plt.bar gives my some weird 3D effect.

Comment: Well, without knowing what is in your `x` it's hard to tell. If `x` isn't spaced evenly, you could try `plt.bar(x, y, width=w, align='edge')` with `w = np.concatente(np.diff(x), [x[-1]-x[-2])` or so.  `np.diff(x)` contains all the differences of `x`; you need to add one extra width for the very last bar.

Comment: @JohanC sorry, the x has the center of the bins, and the y has the height.

Comment: They are not evenly spaced. Actually I am confused by the width parameter now. Is that the width of the bins? I.e. do I need to give that as a parameter to the fit or it can do it automatically as the average between 2 consecutive x's?

Comment: It's the width of the bars. It could be `np.diff(bin_bounds)` if you have access to the original bins. I don't understand what you mean by 'fit' here.